# How to create confirm email callback from repository class in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I want to make an email confirmation callback link from asp.net core web API repository class,
This is easy when done in the controller of the API, but I am having trouble doing this from the repository class.
I keep getting this error:

> Could not find an IRouter associated with the ActionContext. If your application is using endpoint routing then you can get a IUrlHelperFactory with dependency injection and use it to create a UrlHelper, or use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.LinkGenerator.

this is what I  have so far:

this is my repository code for registration:

```cs
public async Task<(bool IsSuccess, string ErrorMessage)> Register(RegisterDTO model)
{
    if (model != null)
    {
         var user = _mapper.Map<ApplicationUser>(model);
         var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
         if (result.Succeeded)
         {
            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
            var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
            string _scheme = _urlHelper.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Scheme;
            //var callbackurl = _urlHelper.Link("ConfirmEmail",  new { email = 
                  user.Email, code = code });
            var callbackurl = 
             _urlHelper.Action("ConfirmEmail",nameof(AccountController), new { email = user.Email, code = code }, _scheme);
            var mailresult = _mailSender.SendEmail(model.Email, "Please confirm your 
            account by clicking here: <a href=\"" + callbackurl + "\">link</a>");
            return (true, "Account created successfully");
        }
        return (false, "Eror occured while creating your account");
    }

    return (false, "Please provide the user data");
}
```

**Account Controller**

```
[HttpGet("{token}/{email}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string token, string email)
{
     var result = await _repository.ConfirmEmail(token, email);
     if (result.IsSuccess)
         return Ok(result.ErrorMessage);
     else
         return BadRequest(result.ErrorMessage);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't do this since it breaks the responsibility of the individual layers. Use the repository (or additional service layer) to identify _what_ the functionality should look like, and then have the controller layer execute it.  A status wrapper object is a reasonable approach for this.

Comment: Thanks for the insigt, please can you give example of how to use that status wrapper object??

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work.
see the code below:

```
enter code here
public async Task<(bool IsSuccess, string ErrorMessage)> 
      Register(RegisterDTO model)
{
    if (model != null)
    {
        var user = _mapper.Map<ApplicationUser>(model);
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
            var _urlHelper = _urlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(
                  _actionContextAccessor.ActionContext);
            var code = await _userManager.
                 GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
            string _scheme = _urlHelper.ActionContext.
                  HttpContext.Request.Scheme;
             var callbackurl = _urlHelper.Action(action: 
                  nameof(AccountController.ConfirmEmail), 
                   controller: "Account", values: 
                   new { email = user.Email, code = code }, 
                   protocol: _scheme);
            var mailresult = _mailSender.SendEmail(model.Email, "Please 
              confirm your account by clicking here: <a href=\"" + 
                    callbackurl + "\">link</a>");
            if (mailresult.IsSuccess)
            {
                 return (true, "Account created successfully, Please visit 
                        your email to confirm your email");
             }
             else
             {
                return (true, $"Account created successfully,  
                       {mailresult.ErrorMessage}");
             }
                
          }
            return (false, result.Errors.ToString());
        }

        return (false, "Please provide the user data");
    }
```